# Dynamically add SubMenuItems to a SubMenu

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a c# menu strip with top-level menu items (TLM items).  I am dynamically adding items to one of the TLM items as follows, which works great.

```
DataRowCollection DRC = DataAccessClass.GetData("SELECT * FROM company ORDER BY CompanyName");
ToolStripMenuItem[] items = new ToolStripMenuItem[DRC.Count];
int itemCounter = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in DRC)
{
  string nm = dr["companyname"].ToString();
  int id = Convert.ToInt16(dr["companyid"].ToString());
  items[itemCounter] = new ToolStripMenuItem();
  items[itemCounter].Name = string.Format("menuitem{0}", itemCounter);
  items[itemCounter].Text = nm;
  items[itemCounter].Click += new EventHandler(MenuItemClickHandler);
  itemCounter++;
}

CompanyToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(items);
```

Once this TLM has been populated, I want to dynamically add sub-menu items to each of the dynamic menu items created above.  I am similarly creating an array of ToolStripMenuItems as above, and I am trying to add them to a menu item using this, shown here for the first menu item:

```
CompanyToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems[0].DropDownItems.AddRange(submenuitems);
```

But it isn't working.  Any ideas?

When I add CompanyToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems[0] to a watch window, it is showing a "DropDownItems" property.  When I try to type it in, the auto-complete drop-down isn't exposing the property as an option.

Comment: `((ToolStripMenuItem)CompanyToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems[0]).DropDownItems.AddRange(submenuitems);`

Comment: I can't mark this as the answer unless you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting the selected DropDownItem item to a ToolStripMenuItem:

```
((ToolStripMenuItem)CompanyToolStripMenuItem.
    DropDownItems[0]).DropDownItems.AddRange(submenuitems);
```